# Create topic in multiple zookeepers with Kafka AdminUtils.CreateTopic JAVA API in Kafka 0.9.0.1 gives Error

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-zookeeper

I am using below code snippet to create topic in multiple zookeepers with Kafka Java APIS. when I specify 2 zookeeprs IPs in zookeeperConnect variable it only creates topic in anyone of zookeeper. Both the zookeeper are 2 different kafka cluster. Any Help ?

```
   String zookeeperConnect = zookeeperIPs; // Multiple zookeeper IPs
   int sessionTimeoutMs = 10 * 1000;
   int connectionTimeoutMs = 8 * 1000;

   try {
    ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient(
                zookeeperConnect,
                sessionTimeoutMs,
                connectionTimeoutMs,
                ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);

    boolean isSecureKafkaCluster = false;
    ZkUtils zkUtils = new ZkUtils(zkClient, 
    new ZkConnection(zookeeperConnect), isSecureKafkaCluster);

        String topic1 = "nameofTopictobeCreated";
        int partitions = 1;
        int replication = 1;
        Properties topicConfig = new Properties(); // add per-topic configurations settings here

        AdminUtils.createTopic(zkUtils, topic1, partitions, replication, topicConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

The tool `AdminUtils` assumes the all specifies ZK belong to the same cluster, and thus it is sufficient to talk to one of them (as ZK nodes will synchronize themselves automatically).

If you want to create a topic in two clusters, you need to issue the command twice, each time using a different ZK node.